# dll is locked and can't be protected

Tags: encryption, visual-studio, dll, locked-files

I am trying to provide protection and encryption for some build artifacts that our code produces (The code is written in c++ and c# and we use visual studio) . The tool that I am using is a product called AxProtectorNet which belongs to Wibu-systems company. While doing the protection (using a batch file in which I passed the dlls and the protector tool location) for one dll i am getting the error saying
`file protected\Ramin.dll is locked.`
I wonder what it means. Does it mean it's already protected? Or is it corrupted? It's worth mentioning that we got the code from another company. So we don't know much about the details on the code.

P.S. I already tried checking if the dll is being used by a process of program etc (through resource monitor)

Comment: Have you tried their support ?  What happens if you run it again on all files - does it say this for all file snow ?

Comment: Double posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75094829/dll-is-locked-and-cant-be-protected

Comment: Probably the tool is locking the DLL itself. As noted on the stackoverflow post, this is a question for AxProtectorNet Support.

Comment: It’s not possible to encrypt C# code and be able to compile it. Like Java an executable can be decompiled. You can make it extremely difficult to understand what the code does but it’s not possible to make it impossible to decompile C# code

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - The best the software can do is make it function names, very confusing, software cannot change how .NET code functions.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - It's junk